# Without solving the quadratic equation find $x_1^2 - x_2^2$

Tags: quadratics

So i'm doing some problems from quadratic equations, this one in particular is supposed to be solved with vieta's formulas, I'm quite lost at what to do since there is a minus here, for example in solving $x_1^2+x_2^2$ for the same equation, its just a matter of adding $+2x_1x_2 -2x_1x_2$ to it and then inserting vieta's formulas in, but I have no idea what to do with -.

\begin{aligned}
& x^2-3 x-10=0 \\
& x_1^2-x_2^2=?
\end{aligned}

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are $x_1,x_2$ the roots of the original quadratic?  How do you distinguish between them or are you only trying to compute this up to sign?  And, of course, we have $x_i^2=3x_i+10$ which simplifies the problem (or, of course, you could just solve the original quadratic).

Comment: Can you compute both $x_1-x_2$ and $x_1+x_2$

Comment: Unless you know $x_1>x_2$ or $x_2<x_1$, this can only be determined up to a sign.

Comment: X1 and X2 are roots, solutions of the original quadratic equation, the result is supposed to be 21 and -21 , but I have no idea how to get to there. Here's the full text of the problem: X1 and X2 are the solutions of the quadratic equation, without solving the equation find x1^2-x2^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT…try using $$(x_1-x_2)^2=(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2$$

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The two zeroes $ \ x_1 \ $ and $ \ x_2 \ $ imply that $ \ x_1^2 - 3 x_1 - 10 \ = \ 0 $ and $ \ x_2^2 - 3 x_2 -10 \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  Subtracting the second equation from the first gives us $ \ x_1^2 - x_2^2 \ - \ 3·(x_1 - x_2) \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ x_1^2 - x_2^2 \ = \ 3·(x_1 - x_2) \ \ .^{*} \ $  Since the difference of the two (real) zeroes of a quadratic polynomial is $ \ | \ x_1 - x_2 \ | \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{a} \ \ , \ \ (a \ = \ 1 \ $ here) with $ \ \Delta \ $ being the discriminant, it is straightforward to calculate the quantity sought.    Because we are taking a difference, the order of the zeroes matters, so what we will obtain is $ \ | \ x_1^2 - x_2^2 \ | \ \ . \ $  (This problem is simple to check since the quadratic polynomial is easily factored.)

$ ^{*}  $ Notice that this is a "disguised" way of writing $ \ x_1^2 - x_2^2 \ = \ (x_1 + x_2)·(x_1 - x_2) \ \ . $